# Relative path resolution not working?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, web, path

I have html file abc.html in `webApp/htmls/abcd/abc.html` . Here I use the form action tag to give the action url as `FORM ACTION="/pqrs"` , I have the servlet situated at `webApp/WEB-INF/classes/xyz/ABC.class` , and the mapping in the web.xml is-->

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TempServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>xyz.ABC</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TempServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pqrs</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But the when I click the form button I get an HTTP: 404 Error as

```
HTTP Status 404 - /webApp/htmls/abcd/pqrs

type Status report

message /webApp/htmls/abcd/pqrs 

description The requested resource (webApp/htmls/abcd/pqrs) is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.5
```

Why is the action still searching in the htmls directory, Why is it not referring to the web.xml??

I am using Apache tomact 7.x as Web-Server with Eclipse Juno as IDE..

Comment: Good question. I encountered the same when trying to write a proxy using Java Servlet API. I cannot help since I don't know the answer.